# ReCAPTCHA placeholder element must be empty

Tags: javascript

On my site (www.csgowulfit.tk) on the withdraw section, I have a recaptcha which upon completion will display items in bot account for people to withdraw. Now in console, I'm getting this error:

```
recaptcha__en.js:370 Uncaught Error: ReCAPTCHA placeholder element must be empty
at pr (recaptcha__en.js:370)
at recaptcha__en.js:375
at br (recaptcha__en.js:365)
at recaptcha__en.js:374
at recaptcha__en.js:385
```

I am more than certain that this is breaking my withdraw code so please help fix it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Not only are you probably violating CS:GO's Terms of Service, but you'll also need to update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** (the recaptcha script) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: You might wanna try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37021241/error-recaptcha-placeholder-element-must-be-empty