# I am unable to login to my overleaf account while using it on microsoft edge. I get a Recaptcha error

Tags: microsoft-edge

I am unable to login to my overleaf account. I receive the following error:

> reCAPTCHA placeholder element must be empty

I tried clearing cache, cookies. A simple google search suggests me some script lines as solution to a similar issue of ReCaptcha. For instance this answer on stackoverflow. [Error: ReCAPTCHA placeholder element must be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37021241/error-recaptcha-placeholder-element-must-be-empty). But I am not clear where to paste/run this script.

Comment: Hi, how about the issue? Is my answer below helpful to deal with the issue? Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution you found is for using google recaptcha library, it's not suitable for your login issue.

To try to deal with the issue, first, you can check if you have installed any extension like Adblock in Edge. You can disable all the extensions in Edge and try again.

Second, when the error appears, you can open F12 devtools in Edge and find recaptcha file in **Sources** tab like below. Then you can press `Ctrl+A` to select all the codes in **api.js?render=explicit** and delect them all. Then press `Ctrl+S` to save the change and login again to see if it works.

[image]

Comment: I did not have a file by name <api.js?render=explicit>. Instead I just had <api.js>. It had 20+ lines starting the same ways as your screenshot. I just pressed <ctrl+A>. I did not delete. I just closed it and reopened my Overleaf and it worked. I am not sure what exaactly happened. But I am sure it is related to your answer. Thanks.

Comment: May be I did delete accidentally after I pressd ctrl+A, and the lines got deleted. I am not sure.

Comment: Is there any side effect by deleting all codes in the `api.js?render=explicit` file?